# amp-html with multiple canonicals

Tags: seo, amp-html, canonical-link

We are working on a site for advertising products that you can purchase in another page (is it called aggregator in English?). For improving SEO, we were recommended to do an AMP version of the page. We did two versions of the web, one "standard" version and an AMP version.

Now we want to keep only [one version](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/prepare_for_discovery#what-if-i-only-have-one-page?). However, according to the SEO guy, we need to place a `link rel="canonical"` on the product page to the original website selling the product. But, according to AMP, we need a `link rel="canonical"` pointing to itself. Can I have two `link rel="canonical"` or is there any other way of solving this having only one version of the web?
Right now we don't have this problem because AMP version points to "standard" version and "standard" version points to original website selling the product.

Comment: is standard version having <linl rel="amphtml" tag now?

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can no use multiple **canonical**  on same page.

You need to do the following

1. Use  link **rel="canonical"** pointing to AMP page
2. Original buy now page link **rel="canonical"** also pointing to AMP page if url is different and content is same.

Comment: Right now we have something like this:
1. example.com/buy/shoe/ --> `link rel="amphtml" href="example.com/amp/buy/shoe/"` and `link rel="canonical" href="other-page.com/buy-this-shoe/"`
2. example.com/amp/buy/shoe/ --> `link rel="canonical" href="example.com/buy/shoe/"`

I would like to have only example.com as an AMP page, but I would need a canonical pointing to itself and another pointing to other-page.com, which is supposed to be impossible. So I guess we'll need to stick to 2 versions of the page :(

Comment: what is the canonical of other-page.com/buy-this-shoe/ and is content same?

Comment: other-page.com is from another company, so we cannot modify their canonical. That page is selling a product and we are advertising that same product in our page and redirecting to them if you want to buy it, so we added the canonical in our page to avoid being marked as duplicated content.

Comment: your page content and other company page content is different so you can put only your url as a canonical

Answer (score 0):

The **[AMP documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec)** => Required markup informs:

> *contain a  tag inside their head **that points to the regular HTML version** of the AMP HTML document or to itself if no such HTML version exists.*
>
> *If an AMP document exists that is an alternative representation of a canonical document, then the canonical document should point to the AMP document via a link tag with the relation "amphtml"*

Therefore, you must specify in the regular version a link to the amp version, 
example: `<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">` 
On the amp version, install `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/canonical/document.html">`

Again, this is confirmed by the documentation:

> *The AMP document itself is expected to point back to its canonical document via a link tag with the relation "canonical".*

Answer (score 0):

I can understand from your question that currently you have two different pages and that you want to keep just one of them, the AMP page. This means the AMP page will not have the corresponding non-AMP page.

In this cases, you have to set the AMP page as its canonical (this means, the AMP page pointing to itself as canonical): `<link rel="canonical" href="url_of_your_amp_page">`